# jquery row cannot be selected after dynamically append html

Tags: jquery

after i append new row in ajax success, this row can not be selected (i use *toggleClass()* and also *hover()*). After googling it is because the event is not binded, and should use *on()* instead of *click()*, but it is still the same

```
$("#simpan").on("click",function(){
              var nim=$("#nim").val();
              var nama=$("#nama").val();
              var alamat=$("#alamat").val();


              $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  url:"data.php?action=getdata",
                  data:"nim="+nim+"&nama="+nama+"&alamat="+alamat,
                  success:function(data){
                       $("table").append(data);
                       resetForm();
                  }
              });

          });
```

you guys have solution?

**update:**
here's the event handler of the row

```
$("tr").not(":first").click(function(){
     $("tr").not(this).removeClass("selected");
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

my table

```
<table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
          <td>Nim</td>
          <td>Nama</td>
          <td>Alamat</td>
      </tr>

      <?php
        include "db.php";
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mahasiswa");
        while($mahasiswa=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>

      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $mahasiswa["nim"]; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $mahasiswa["nama"]; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $mahasiswa["alamat"]; ?></td>
      </tr>

      <?php
        } 
      ?>

    </table>
```

**"simpan"** is a button, when it is clicked, the data in the form is saved to database using ajax and when success, **data** is appended to the table.

```
echo "
      <tr>
        <td>$_POST[nim]</td>
        <td>$_POST[nama]</td>
        <td>$_POST[alamat]</td>
      </tr>
    ";
```

Comment: We don't really need to see the code where you append the rows, but the event handlers for the rows themselves would be more interesting.

Comment: Please include the HTML for the table you are working with.

Comment: `$("#simpan")` who's id is it?

Comment: @adeneo and **SpencerLeland** i have updated the question  **Jai** it's the id of the "save" button

Comment: You'll need to replace `$("tr").not(":first").click(function(){ ... });` with `$('#table').on('click', 'tr:gt(0)', function(){ ... });`

Comment: @adeneo it works, thank you very much, and thank to all of you who wanted to help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#simpan", function(){
    var nim=$("#nim").val();
    var nama=$("#nama").val();
    var alamat=$("#alamat").val();


    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"data.php?action=getdata",
        data:"nim="+nim+"&nama="+nama+"&alamat="+alamat,
        success:function(data){
        $("table").append(data);
        resetForm();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think the element with ID #simpan is the rows, looks like it's the parent, otherwise multiple ID's would be an issue as well.

Comment: @adeneo my guess is that this is the selector, because he is saying that he has switched it to `on`, but he is using the wrong syntax though. However, you are right, about the id selector, If I am correct, he needs to switch the id to a class

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added element syntax of `on()` is like:

```
$(staticPanentElement).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

Where `staticPanentElement` means any valid selector that point to an item that is not dynamically created and contains the `target`.

***And in your code it seems you're using multiple rows with same `id=simpan` and that is not acceptable.***